# How to change the background color of a edge label in GraphViz

Tags: graphviz

I am wanting to change the background color of an edge label in Graphviz.  At the moment the only way I can see of doing this is using an HTML table.

Eg,

```
edge [len=3,fontcolor=red];
DeviceA -- DeviceB [headlabel=<
    <table border="0" cellborder="0">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="white">Head Label</td>
        </tr>
    </table>>
,taillabel="Tail Label"];
```

What I would like to be able to do is something shorter/cleaner:

```
edge [len=3,fontcolor=red,bgcolour=white];
DeviceA -- DeviceB [headlabel="Head Label",taillabel="Tail Label"];
```

Is their an option for this in graphviz?

The reason I am trying to do this is because end labels end up written over edges, which makes the label difficult to read, a background color the same color as the canvas, artificially creates a break in the edge.

Thanks

Comment: Try fillcolor = white

Comment: Thanks for the idea, unfortunately that doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In GraphViz there is no way to change the Background Colour of an Edge Label.  However you can achieve the same by using a HTML Table:

Eg:

```
edge [len=3,fontcolor=red];
DeviceA -- DeviceB [headlabel=<
    <table border="0" cellborder="0">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="white">Head Label</td>
        </tr>
    </table>>
,taillabel="Tail Label"];
```

Comment: Thanks! It's quite incredible that there isn't this basic functionality integrated in the label options...